# "this" keyword is not working inside jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use "this" keyword within my jquery function but it doesn't works for me...

i have tried following ways:

1...
Not works....

```
function getRequest() {

      var ReqPlace = $(this).parent('div.reqHere').parent('div.allReqs').children('div.reqHere');
}
```

2..
Not works....

```
var that=this;   //also tried var that=$(this);

function getRequest() {

      var ReqPlace = $(that).parent('div.reqHere').parent('div.allReqs').children('div.reqHere');
}
```

3..
Works but this time i have used a button

```
<input type="button" onclick="getRequest(this);" />

function getRequest(that) {

      var ReqPlace = $(that).parent('div.reqHere').parent('div.allReqs').children('div.reqHere');
}
```

> The above 3rd step is works pretty good but i don't need a button  **Is there any other way to use "this" keyword inside function**

Thanks

Comment: how are you calling `getRequest` in the first and second attempts

Comment: Read  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to learn how `this` works. The second attempts is certainly incorrect. What do you expect `this` to refer to there and why?

Comment: this is global object if you are not specifying into onclick function

Comment: what is it you expect/want `this` to be when you call `getRequest`?

Comment: @Arun i'm calling it like this:

setInterval(function () {
            getRequest();
        }, 4000);

Comment: @JaromandaX

i'm using "this" to get a specific div/object e.g..

Comment: do you expect `this` to just know what you want it to be? You'll need to show a **lot** more context than just a `setInterval` if you expect anyone to figure out what it is you want to do - P.S. `this` in a setInterval callback will be `window` or `undefined` depending on strictness

Answer (score 1):

**this** returns the instance of the object in which it was called.

In your case it does not work in **statement 1** because for some reason you called **this** out of nowhere and returns you the instance of the function instead that is why it is not working

Same goes to **statement 2** consider if the declaration

```
var that = this;
```

if this is inside a function **this** will return a function as well that is why it is not working.

And finally the reason **statement 3** is working is it's returning the html object instance of the element since the function is a click event listener of an element. Take note that calling **this** in the function using **statement 3** will work as well.

Well you can always use **this** in a function but remember that

```
$(query)
jQuery(query)
```

where **query** is an HTMLObject or an html string or a css selector string, sending it with a function will cause an error.

If you want to do something like this code inside a function

```
$(this).parent('div.reqHere').parent('div.allReqs').children('div.reqHere');
```

unless **this** is an HTML Object, what you should do is:

```
<div class='somedivinyourtemplate' id='hello'>
</div>

function () {
    $('#hello').parent('div.reqHere')
        .parent('div.allReqs').children('div.reqHere')
}
```

or just simply put an id of the element you want to select.

Hope that helps you understand how it works

Comment: *"inside a function this will return a function as well"* `this` rarely refers to a function. What do you think `this` refers to here?

Comment: @Preez Thanks it really works but will it point a specific div....i used "this" for specific.....

Comment: @Heartlion the answer is no but in some cases it will work when you call **this** inside a callback function of onclick, onchange, onwhatever of the **specific div** you want then the answer is yes.

Comment: @FelixKling my bad didn't notice it, I just mis-wrote it it should be something like an assumption as he did not include what wraps the code

Answer (score -1):

**if you want to use "this" in jquery**

*give id to button*

```
<input type="button" id="getrequest" />
```

*then*

```
 $("#getrequest").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div.reqHere').parent('div.allReqs').children('div.reqHere')
    })
```

Comment: see the bit where he says `but i don't need a button`

Comment: @Akshay thanks for answering but this is not what i'm asking in question...
i just don't ANY BUTTON .... i said in the 3rd step that the getRequest() function fired with button but not on loading...